# How to edit my Playstation 5 4K gameplay?

Tags: video, editing, mp4, video-capture, premiere-pro

Members. I'm facing a few issues while trying to edit 4K gameplay footage from my PS5. PS5 has two options to capture gameplay:

1. 1080P (.mp4)
2. 4K (.webm)

First, the captured 4K footage extension is .webm, and neither Premier Pro nor DaVinci Resolve natively support the mentioned extension. Even after using a third party plugin called WebM at https://www.fnordware.com/WebM/ for Premier Pro to support the .webm file,  the preview is laggy, and the colour Contrast and Brightness are messed up (Footage looks whitish). Is there a way to edit captured gameplay in Premier Pro without losing video quality?

I have read about using **FFMPEG** to convert .webm to .mp4 without losing quality (or minimal quality loss). I didn't try converting as I was confused with the parameters. I'm a beginner, and I don't know how to get going with editing in this case. All your guidance and support is highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Adobe themselves recommend the fnord webm plugin, so you may just have installed with incorrect options.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @DrMayhem. Can you please guide me on how to use and properly install the Fnord's Webm plugin?

Comment: I would follow the guidance that Adobe provide on their Premiere help pages.